# a bad Shutdown resulting in a flashing folder with question mark

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup, unix

I was rebooting my MBP when i turned off abruptly, now when i turn on my Mac again i just see a Flasing folder icon with a question mark instead the Apple Logo.

i have MacBook Pro 15" Late 2012 (Non retina)
Bootcamp (MacOS X Yosemite - Windows 10)
The HFS+ partition currently has Journaling Enabled (i didn't find a way to disable outside MacOS X, that i can't use it rigth now)

What have i tried so far:

- Initialize Recovery Partition ( no partition in the hard drive is recognized by the EFI loader)
- Using Disk Utilities **[Internet Recovery]** (the partiotions doesn't appears on the utility application)
- Trying to install Mac OSX from Internet recovery (But Hard drive doesn't appears on drive selection menu.
- Booted with Ubuntu 14.04 LiveCD tried fsck.hfsplus on it ( Ubuntu can actually see all the partitions and running fsck with foce parameter reports everything its OK with partition).

I don't know what to do ...

Comment: Did you try Safe mode or the Verbose mode?

Comment: no, tried Verbose Safe mode (Option + Command + V) and booted

Comment: O.o - now booted normally ... WTF, really don't know what happened

Comment: hehe, just got stuck in the boot loop, but you fixed that using the Verbose mode :). Shall we make that a answer so we can close this question ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes, sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes booting in Safe mode or in Verbose mode will ratify the boot log problems.

Safe mode "Shift"

Verbose Mode "cmd-v"

or Press Option during startup  Start up in Startup Manager, where you can select an OS X volume or network volume to start from.